# Layering text and images in Canvas HTML5

Tags: css, ipad, html, canvas

Hi am making a small HTML5 canvas demo.

I initiated the canvas using modernizer from O'Reilly's HTML5 text.

This is for iPad so my canvas is 1024 by 768.

I then load in a background image in my DrawScreen function.

```
var backgroundImage = new Image();
backgroundImage.src = "images/background.jpg";
backgroundImage.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(backgroundImage,0,0);
}
```

I want to add text to this then. So I do:

```
function drawText(){
    context.fillStyle ="gray";
    context.font = "28px Helvetica";        
    context.fillText(message, 260, 700);
}
```

I then call both functions:

```
    DrawScreen();
    DrawText();
```

However my background image totally over writes my text. Or is on top of it. If I disable DrawScreen(); I can see the text. Changing the function order doesn't make a differnce...

How to do this? I feel so stupid that am stuck on something that seems so elementary.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that your image is being drawn after -- and therefore on top of -- your text. This is because of the time it takes the image to load. Basically, what's happening is this:

- You call your DrawScreen function
- You start loading your background image by assigning the src attribute
- You assign the onload() handler to fire once the image has finished loading.
- DrawScreen exits, having completed all its work
- You call DrawText, which immediately draws the text
- At some point later, the image finishes loading, fires the onload() event, and you draw the background image.

I'd suggest restructuring your code so that *all* the drawing is kicked off by the successful loading of the image. That way, nothing asynchronous will be going on, and the image will be drawn, followed by the text.

[Here's a quick example, on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/SpGfS/1/).

Comment: Problem is as matt pointed out ... add DrawText(); to the end of backgroundImage.onload = function()

Comment: Matt was right I was not loading elements in correct order! So the text was rendered before the image itself was. Thank you.